# Different colors for ranges in the same DataSource

Tags: java, jfreechart

I`ve got TimeSeries Chart with only one TimeSeries. I need to highlight ranges, that applying my condition.

```
final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("USD");
    for (IncomeBalanceState incomeBalanceState : incomeBalanceStates) {
        if (incomeBalanceState.getIncomeType() == FuturesIncomeType.COMMISSION) continue; 
        if (incomeBalance.getIncomeType() == FuturesIncomeType.TRANSFER)
       /*set color */
        series.addOrUpdate(dateTimeToDay(incomeBalanceState.getDateTime()),
                incomeBalanceState.getAvailableBalance());
    }
```

Comment: See `org.jfree.chart.plot.Marker`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20IntervalMarker).

Comment: Also consider suitable `org.jfree.chart.annotations`.